# how should i create a list of items that filter on drop down item selection in bootsrap?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to filter my list items on page from the selection in drop down menu (like on eCommerce site filters are working and grid items changes respectively )how to achieve this in bootstrap?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What have you tried?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score -1):

Use this library. https://select2.github.io/examples.html

You can use multiple select boxes.